# Excluding Files From Jar With build-helper-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have some test related classes that I want to exclude from the compiled jar output for a project. This is a legacy project and I don't want to lose existing revision history by moving the classes to src/test. Since I am already using build-helper-maven-plugin I thought I would be able to specify an exclusion pattern there, but so far nothing I have tried seems to work. I run

> mvn clean install package

in my project root and I see the log message

> [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:add-source (add-source) @
> Person-ejb --- [INFO] Source directory:
> /media/psf/Home/Documents/workspace/optics/optics/Person/ejb/src
> added.

but when I look at the compiled jar it still containts the test directory and its contents. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

**My pom.xml:**

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <sources>
                    <source>src/</source>
                  </sources>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/test/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              
              <execution>
                <id>add-reource</id>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>add-resource</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>resources/</directory>
                    </resource>
                  </resources>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: I don't understand this: ` I don't want to lose existing revision history by moving the classes to src/test. ` that is exactly for what a version control system is intended to record... Move your classes / files to correct locations (`src/main/java` and `src/test/java` and `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources etc.);  and you can rid of build-helper-maven-plugin ... etc.

Comment: Furthermore read about the maven lifecycle because `mvn clean install package` this means your are running several things in duplicate... only use `mvn clean package` ... or if you have integration tests use `mvn clean verify` but do not use `install` ...

Comment: @ khmarbaise The install command is just a leftover. Normally I run things via the maven wildfly plugin but I was trying to run things at a bit of a lower level to figure out my issues.

Comment: Running via wildfly will not handle things correctly ... wildfly plugin is as far as I know only for deployment ?

Comment: @ khmarbaise Just to clarify about this history. If I do a git mv on a file it breaks the chain of custody. Any changes I make going forward would be recorded. If I want to do a compare of a change to a point before the move however, it would be impossible since git is treating the moved resource as a new file.

Comment: Really ? You seemed to misunderstand git you can follow a rename via `git log --follow filename`...

Comment: I have literally the same issue.  Why do you think there exists an <exclude> attribute?  I really want to solve this same exact issue without creating multiple pom files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Context

I believe this is a bug in *build-helper-maven-plugin* or possibly a misprint in the usage [documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).  The `<excludes>` tag is completely ignored by the plugin.

> It does not even appear in the code completion in Eclipse
> [image: code completion]

## Solution

While you can't exclude files in the builder-helper-maven-plugin, you can exclude files in the *maven-compiler-plugin*.  So if you simply add the following configuration to your *maven-compiler-plugin* it should exclude the `**/test/**` directories

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/test/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

## Best Practice

I feel obligated to remind the reader that this is an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Software_design) in maven.  Ideally you would create separate pom files for each source directory, then add them as separate modules in your parent pom file.  I realize this may be a larger refactoring effort though

Comment: I think you are correct. Looking at the documentation for the build helper plugin again, I mixed up the examples for source and resources. Excludes is only available for resources, it does nothing for source. I will try your suggestion with the compiler plugin and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes please report back and let me know if it works for your use case.  I came across your question researching the same exact issue, tried this implementation instead and it worked fine for me

Comment: Nice workaround. Thanks!